# Filter log file entries between 2 timestamps particularly [31/Jul/2018:21:36:18 -0700] format

Tags: bash, awk

I am looking to get the filtered log between 2 timestamps [31/Jul/2018:21:36:18 -0700] and  [31/Jul/2018:21:38:14 -0700]
and want to get an output

```
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:36:18 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:36:18 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:38:14 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048
```

This is how my log file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:36:18 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:36:18 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:36:18 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:38:14 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048
127.0.0.1 - vbhore [31/Jul/2018:21:38:14 -0700] "GET /home.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2048

Vinays-MacBook-Pro-2:access_log vinaybhore$ awk -v d1="$(date --date="-1 min" "+%b %_d %H:%M")" -v d2="$(date "+%b %_d %H:%M")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2' log.txt 
date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

could you please help?
I also tried

```
awk -v dt="$(date -d '1 hour ago' "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")" '$0 ~ dt' log.txt
grep "^$(date -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" log.txt
```

Comment: It looks like you're using quotes inside quotes and that is breaking your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The `date` command is not fast enough and invoking it for each line may not be time-efficient if the log file is lengthy.
A convenient way to compare date&time is to convert it to a `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` form instead of converting it to the time since the epoch.
For instance, '31/Jul/2018:21:36:18' will be represented as 20180731213618. Then you can compare the numbers.
Then how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

from='31/Jul/2018:21:36:18'
to='31/Jul/2018:21:38:14'

awk -v from="$from" -v to="$to" 'BEGIN {
        monstr = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
        for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            mon2mm[substr(monstr, i * 3 - 2, 3)] = sprintf("%02d", i);
        }
        fromts = mytimestamp(from);
        tots = mytimestamp(to);
    }

    $4 ~ /\[[0-9][0-9]\// {
        logts = mytimestamp(substr($4, 2));
        if (logts >= fromts && logts <= tots) {
            print $0;
        }
    }

    function mytimestamp(str,
        ary, ts) {
        split(str, ary, /[/:]/);
        ts = ary[3] mon2mm[ary[2]] ary[1] ary[4] ary[5] ary[6];
        return ts;
    }
' log.txt
```

Comment: Remark: this solution will not work due to daylight saving time. You might notice the availability of the time-zone. This will change when daylight saving time become active. The best is to convert this to UNIX epoch!